# Is the Yoneda Lemma only useful from a theoretical point of view?

Tags: haskell, functor, function-composition

For instance, loop fusion can be obtained with Yoneda:

```
newtype Yoneda f a =
    Yoneda (forall b. (a -> b) -> f b)

liftYo :: (Functor f) => f a -> Yoneda f a
liftYo x = Yoneda $ \f -> fmap f x

lowerYo :: (Functor f) => Yoneda f a -> f a
lowerYo (Yoneda y) = y id

instance Functor (Yoneda f) where
    fmap f (Yoneda y) = Yoneda $ \g -> y (g . f)

loopFusion = lowerYo . fmap f . fmap g . liftYo
```

But I could have just written `loopFusion = fmap (f . g)`. Why would I use `Yoneda` at all? Are there other use cases?

Comment: As your last instance implies, `Yoneda f` is a functor even when `f` is not. `lowerYo` does not require `Functor f`. So, you can think of `Yoneda f` as a way to "force" `f` to become a functor, a sort of "completion", if you wish.

Comment: Yes, `lowerYo` is wrong and the code comes from a gist. Funnily enough I didn't wind up with a functor constraint when I translated the code into Javascript `yoCata = tx => tx.runYoneda(id)`.

Comment: So when I have a type without a functor instance instead of defining one I can just write a lambda with the mapping logic and pass it to the `Yoneda` constructor - is that what you mean?

Comment: I don't have a clear practical application in mind, but for certain data constructors `F` it is impossible to define a lawful `Functor` instance, while `Yoneda F` would be a functor nevertheless. (However, in such case, defining a value of type `Yoneda F a` might be hard.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, *in this case* you could have done fusion by hand, because the two `fmap`s are "visible" in the source code, but the point is that `Yoneda` does the transformation at runtime. It's a dynamic thing, most useful when you *don't know* how many times you will need to `fmap` over a structure. E.g. consider lambda terms:

```
data Term v = Var v | App (Term v) (Term v) | Lam (Term (Maybe v))
```

The `Maybe` under `Lam` represents the variable bound by the abstraction; in the body of a `Lam`, the variable `Nothing` refers to the bound variable, and all variables `Just v` represent the ones bound in the environment. `(>>=) :: Term v -> (v -> Term v') -> Term v'` represents substitution—each `v`ariable can be replaced with a `Term`. However, when replacing a variable inside a `Lam`, all the variables in the produced `Term` need to be wrapped in `Just`. E.g.

```
Lam $ Lam $ Var $ Just $ Just $ ()
  >>= \() -> App (Var "f") (Var "x")
=
Lam $ Lam $ App (Var $ Just $ Just "f") (Var $ Just $ Just "x")
```

The naive implementation of `(>>=)` goes like this:

```
(>>=) :: Term v -> (v -> Term v') -> Term v'
Var x >>= f = f x
App l r >>= f = App (l >>= f) (r >>= f)
Lam b >>= f = Lam (b >>= maybe (Var Nothing) (fmap Just . f))
```

But, written like this, every `Lam` that `(>>=)` goes under adds an `fmap Just` to `f`. If I had a `Var v` buried under 1000 `Lam`s, then I would end up calling `fmap Just` and iterating over the new `f v` term 1000 times! I can't just pull your trick and fuse multiple `fmap`s into one, by hand, because there's only one `fmap` in the source code being called multiple times.

`Yoneda` can ease the pain:

```
bindTerm :: Term v -> (v -> Yoneda Term v') -> Term v'
bindTerm (Var x) f = lowerYoneda (f x)
bindTerm (App l r) f = App (bindTerm l f) (bindTerm r f)
bindTerm (Lam b) f =
  Lam (bindTerm b (maybe (liftYoneda $ Var Nothing) (fmap Just . f)))

(>>=) :: Term v -> (v -> Term v') -> Term v'
t >>= f = bindTerm t (liftYoneda . f)
```

Now, the `fmap Just` is free; it's just a wonky function composition. The actual iteration over the produced `Term` is in the `lowerYoneda`, which is only called once for each `Var`. To reiterate: the source code nowhere contains anything of the form `fmap f (fmap g x)`. Such forms only arise at runtime, dynamically, depending on the argument to `(>>=)`. `Yoneda` can rewrite that, *at runtime*, to `fmap (f . g) x`, even though you can't rewrite it like that in the source code. Further, you can add `Yoneda` to existing code with minimal changes to it. (There is, however, a drawback: `lowerYoneda` is *always* called exactly once for each `Var`, which means e.g. `Var v >>= f = fmap id (f v)` where it was just `f v`, before.)

Answer (score 5):

There is an example similar in spirit to [the one described by HTNW](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56481790/2751851) in *lens*. A look at (a paraphrased version of) [the `lens` function](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.17.1/docs/Control-Lens-Lens.html#v:lens) illustrates what a typical van Laarhoven lens looks like:

```
-- type Lens s t a b = forall f. Functor f => (a -> f b) -> s -> f t
lens :: (s -> a) -> (s -> b -> t) -> Lens s t a b
lens getter setter = \f -> \s -> fmap (setter s) (f (getter s))
```

The occurrence of `fmap` in there means that composing lenses will, in principle, lead to consecutive uses of `fmap`. Now, most of the time this doesn't actually matter: the implementations in *lens* use a lot of inlining and newtype coercion so that, when using the *lens* combinators (`view`, `over`, and so forth), the involved functor (typically `Const` or `Identity`) is generally optimised away. In a few situations, however, it is not possible to do that (for instance, if the lens is used in such a way that a concrete choice of functor isn't done in compile time). As compensation, *lens* offers a helper function called [`fusing`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.17.1/docs/Control-Lens-Lens.html#v:fusing), which makes it possible to have `fmap` fusion in those special cases. Its implementation is:

```
-- type LensLike f s t a b = (a -> f b) -> s -> f t
fusing :: Functor f => LensLike (Yoneda f) s t a b -> LensLike f s t a b
fusing t = \f -> lowerYoneda . t (liftYoneda . f)
```

That being so, if you write `fusing (foo . bar)`, `Yoneda f` is picked as the functor to be used by `foo . bar`, which guarantees `fmap` fusion.

(This answer was inspired by [a comment by Edward Kmett](https://reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/5715b3/when_can_i_expect_overhead_for_lens/d8o3e8t/), which I happened to stumble upon right before seeing this question.)